# Can't provision EC2 instance with ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to provision an EC2 instance with Ansible installed on an EC2 Ubuntu instance, after provisioning a VPC. This is the contents of my `bastion-instance.yml` file:

```yaml
- name: Setup Vprofile Bastion Host
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Import bastion setup variables
      include_vars: vars/bastion_setup

    - name: Import VPC output variables
      include_vars: vars/output_vars

    - name: Create vprofile ec2 keys
      ec2_key:
        name: vprofile-key
        region: "{{region}}"
      register: key_out
    
    - name: Save private key into file bastion-key-pem
      copy: 
        content: "{{key_out.key.private_key}}"
        dest: "./bastion-key.pem"
        mode: 0600
      when: key_out.changed
    
    - name: Create sec grp for bastion hosts
      ec2_group:
        name: Bastion-host-sg
        description: Allow port 22 from everywhere and all port within sg
        region: "{{region}}"
        vpc_id: "{{vpcid}}"
        rules:
          - proto: tcp
            from_port: 22
            to_port: 22
            cidr_ip: "{{MYIP}}"
      register: BastionSG_out
    
    - name: creating Bastion Host
      ec2:
        key_name: vprofile-key
        region: "{{region}}"
        instance_type: t2.micro
        image: "{{bastion_ami}}"
        group_id: "{{BastionSG_out.group_id}}"
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{pubsub1id}}"
        wait: yes #wait until healthcheck is ok
        wait_timeout: 300
        instance_tags:
          Name: "Bastion_host"
          Project: Vprofile
          Owner: DevOps Team
        exact_count: 1 #to make sure we wont create ec2 instance every run
        count_tag: Name #count matched tags
      register: BastionHost_out
```

When I run this playbook, the security group and key pair are successfully provisioned, but I receive the following error for the instance provisioning:

> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: `UnknownParameter`The parameter MetadataOptions is not recognized082b8b0f-bf75-409e-985c-386068293e5f
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"boto3_version": "1.20.34", "botocore_version": "1.23.34", "changed": false, "msg": "Instance creation failed: The parameter MetadataOptions is not recognized"}

I tried running a basic testing EC2 instance with the required parameters only, but also got no luck. I don't understand where this `MetadataOptions` came from since I did not use a parameter with this name.

When running the playbook with `-vvv`, the following is the log:

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_ec2_payload_zt20ipz8/ansible_ec2_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/modules/ec2.py", line 1171, in create_instances
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 976, in run_instances
    return self.get_object('RunInstances', params, Reservation,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1208, in get_object
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>UnknownParameter</Code><Message>The parameter MetadataOptions is not recognized</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>f37105b6-56ef-4add-9aed-6a9f78bdb830</RequestID></Response>
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "boto3_version": "1.20.34",
    "botocore_version": "1.23.34",
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "assign_public_ip": null,
            "aws_access_key": null,
            "aws_ca_bundle": null,
            "aws_config": null,
            "aws_secret_key": null,
            "count": 1,
            "count_tag": {
                "Name": "Bastion_host",
                "Owner": "DevOps Team",
                "Project": "Vprofile"
            },
            "debug_botocore_endpoint_logs": false,
            "ebs_optimized": false,
            "ec2_url": null,
            "exact_count": 1,
            "group": null,
            "group_id": [
                "sg-088e3d11d4742c693"
            ],
            "id": null,
            "image": "ami-022e1a32d3f742bd8",
            "instance_ids": null,
            "instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior": "stop",
            "instance_profile_name": null,
            "instance_tags": {
                "Name": "Bastion_host",
                "Owner": "DevOps Team",
                "Project": "Vprofile"
            },
            "instance_type": "t2.micro",
            "kernel": null,
            "key_name": "vprofile-key",
            "monitoring": false,
            "network_interfaces": null,
            "placement_group": null,
            "private_ip": null,
            "profile": null,
            "ramdisk": null,
            "region": "us-east-1",
            "security_token": null,
            "source_dest_check": null,
            "spot_launch_group": null,
            "spot_price": null,
            "spot_type": "one-time",
            "spot_wait_timeout": 600,
            "state": "present",
            "tenancy": "default",
            "termination_protection": null,
            "user_data": null,
            "validate_certs": true,
            "volumes": null,
            "vpc_subnet_id": "subnet-0c755f0ccdf5face2",
            "wait": true,
            "wait_timeout": 300,
            "zone": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "Instance creation failed: The parameter MetadataOptions is not recognized"
}
```

I searched the internet for a solution to this problem, but didn't find anything similar. I am using Ansible version 2.10. Does anyone have any idea what is causing this issue?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Before anything else, I'd make sure I'm using the latest stack to communicate with Amazon. And this is obviously not the case. As a simple example, you are using the module name [`ec2_group`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_group_module.html) which is now a redirect to [`amazon.aws.ec2_security_group`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_security_group_module.html#ansible-collections-amazon-aws-ec2-security-group-module) which states that the minimum dependency versions are 1.25.0 for `botocore` and 1.22.0 for `boto3`.

Comment: So upgrade your ansible version if needed (the up-to-date and still maintained version is ansible-core 2.14 which you can install with ansible 7.x.x). If you installed ansible-core only, make sure you have the latest `amazon.aws` collection installed. Then upgrade the needed dependencies through pip.

Comment: Thank you! that was indeed the problem. Apperantly apt install does not installing the latest version. pip install --upgrade boto3 botocore did the job. anyway, I upgraded ansible too. Thanks for the help! can you repost the comment as an answer so I will mark it?